# How do I refresh ng-repeat after an Angular Update

Tags: angularjs

Using the code below, I am able to add items in my database, but the table showing the current entries doesn't update (I thought Angular did that automatically?) --- How do I force a refresh of the data?

```
.controller("addItemsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyContacts')/items";
                var vm = $scope;
                var requestDigest = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                vm.addContact = function () {
                    return $http({
                        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest, "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            'Title': vm.LastName,
                            'FirstName': vm.FirstName,
                            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.MyContactsListItem" }
                        }
                    })
                    .then(saveContact)
                    .catch(function (message) {
                        console.log("addContact() error: " + message);
                    });
                    function saveContact(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("Item Added Successfully");
                        return data.data.d;
                    }
                }
            })
```

**NOTE:** I tried using *$scope.contacts.push(data)* as suggested elsewhere in the forum, but contacts came back undefined (?!)

Comment: insert of that alert why not add `console.log(data)` and share with us what it says

Comment: Can you share your view where you are displaying your table as well?

Comment: <div ng-app="spApp">
        <div ng-controller="viewItemsController">
            <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                {{contact.ID}}: {{contact.Title}}, {{contact.FirstName}}
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: @e4c5 - I don't see an easy way to share the data. There are so many fields and subfields. (It's a SharePoint listitem.) Was there one you were looking for in particular?

Comment: no nothing in particular if it is not undefined leave that for the moment. but elaborate on ` I tried using $scope.contacts.push(data) as suggested elsewhere in the forum, but contacts came back undefined (?!)`

Comment: in actual fact your question isn't an MCVE because it doesn't given an exact error and doesn't show some important things like how $scope.contacts is defined and how it's rendered

Comment: var spApp = angular
                .module("spApp", [])
                
                .controller("viewItemsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                     $http(
                    {
                        method: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
                    }
                    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.contacts = data.d.results;
                    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

Comment: That's the only place contacts is used outside of the ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/jimshelley/4uthqd1q/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144388/discussion-between-jimshelley-and-e4c5).

Comment: you are not getting the added contact from database after adding it. try getting data from viewItemsController after you add the contact